# Mapping Subclass OF DTO into ViewModel

Tags: valueinjecter

My DTO class contains another sub class say,

```
Class ABC_DTO
{
   public String XYZ {get;set;}

   public BCD_DTO BCD {get;set;}
}

Class BCD_DTO 
{
     public string Name {get;set;}
     public string Age  {get;set;}
}


//This is Viewmodel

class PQR_ViewModel
{

    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Age  {get;set;}
    public String XYZ {get;set;}
}


How can i map above Dto ABC_DTO into PQR_ViewModel using ValueInjecter?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var viewModel = new PQR_ViewModel();

viewModel.InjectFrom(abc);
viewModel.InjectFrom(abc.BCD);
```

Comment: Instead of doing this for each nested class, Is there any Injection available which automatically map all nested class.

Comment: I had the same question. I went with AutoMapper, which is more powerful in that way, or at least I could find better examples